# Get content into variable

Tags: javascript, json

I get only `[]` in console. The function is asynchronous, and the `console.log` runs before `function(content)`. I understand that, but, I can't resolve it.

```
async function fja() {
    var mydata = [];    

    await Neutralino.storage.getData('notes', function(content) {
        var mydata = content;
    })

    console.log(mydata);
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare the variable outside the function:

```
let data;
```

Then, inside the function:

```
data = content;
```

Comment: Could you update your question to show how you've done it?

Comment: if I put console.log in new function and start it manually then i get data.

Comment: You've done it correctly, but, if `Neutralino.storage.getData` is asynchronous you'll have to await the results before you can log it to the console

Comment: If `Neutralino.storage.getData` is *inside* a function, you can make it `async` and then `await Neutralino.storage.getData`. If not, try adding a [`.then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) onto the closing bracket.

Comment: I try evrthing but i cant get console.log(mydata). its always empty

Comment: You have to show me how you're doing it or I can't help you. If all you've done is the updated code in your question, that won't work as it's asynchronous

Comment: I have updated my questions with newest code

Comment: It should be `myData = content` without the `var`

Comment: it is still [].

Comment: [It should work](https://jsfiddle.net/3qyj06mh/), there must be another reason.

Comment: OK! thank you very much for your time. I will ask author of neutralinojs.

Comment: Author of neutralinojs told me that Neutralinojs uses ie11 component on Windows.   await and Promises are not suported.